# windbg crash dump analysis, high cpu usage -

Tags: memory, gzip, windbg

My application(web api) is suffering with high cpu, while analyzing dump, I see my most of the threads have this !dumpstack -:

```
  Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee
00000030497bec00 00007ffbb19e1118 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x94, 

    calling ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
    00000030497beca0 00007ffba8375dda clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+0xee, calling kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx
    00000030497becd0 00007ffba837345d clr!GCCoop::GCCoop+0xe, calling clr!GetThread
    00000030497bed60 00007ffba8375842 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x482, calling clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait
    00000030497bee00 00007ffba8393e1e clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
    00000030497bee30 00007ffbb19e1f86 KERNELBASE!ConsoleCallServerGeneric+0xf2, calling KERNELBASE!_security_check_cookie
    00000030497bee50 00007ffbb45011a5 ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext+0x355, calling ntdll!memset
    00000030497beed0 00007ffbb450d0c6 ntdll!LdrpGetProcedureAddress+0x66, calling ntdll!RtlImageNtHeaderEx
    00000030497bef50 00007ffbb450c6f5 ntdll!LdrpResolveNonStaticDependency+0x1cd, calling ntdll!LdrpDereferenceNode
    00000030497befd0 00007ffbb4500d07 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xd7, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
    00000030497bf000 00007ffbb45011a5 ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext+0x355, calling ntdll!memset
    00000030497bf020 00007ffbb450f5f3 ntdll!LdrGetProcedureAddressForCaller+0x153, calling ntdll!_security_check_cookie
    00000030497bf030 00007ffb93fc8c84 mfc120u!DllMain+0x210, calling mfc120u!__security_check_cookie
    00000030497bf080 00007ffba8ce2cbb mscoreei!operator delete+0x34, calling kernel32!HeapFreeStub
    00000030497bf0d0 00007ffbb4500d07 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xd7, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
    00000030497bf140 00007ffbb4500d07 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xd7, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
    00000030497bf180 00007ffbac0c51bd gzip!DllMainCRTStartup+0x139, calling gzip!DllMain
    00000030497bf1e0 00007ffb979dbc9d clrcompression!calloc_impl+0x5d, calling ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap
    00000030497bf210 00007ffb979d8eff clrcompression!initptd+0xb7, calling clrcompression!unlock
    00000030497bf230 00007ffbb44ebf57 ntdll!RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast+0xc7, calling ntdll!_security_check_cookie
    00000030497bf240 00007ffb979d7919 clrcompression!CRT_INIT+0x135, calling kernel32!GetCurrentThreadId
    00000030497bf270 00007ffb979d7a0e clrcompression!__DllMainCRTStartup+0x8a, calling clrcompression!DllMain
    00000030497bf280 0000000056b32052 msvcr100!_initptd+0xaa, calling msvcr100!_unlock
    00000030497bf2a0 00007ffbac051779 IitTlsCleanupHelper!UnregisterTLSCleanupCallback+0x679, calling IitTlsCleanupHelper!UnregisterTLSCleanupCallback+0xf0
    00000030497bf2b0 0000000056b31308 msvcr100!__CRTDLL_INIT+0x16c, calling msvcr100!_CrtEndBoot
    00000030497bf2d0 00007ffbb450bee8 ntdll!LdrpReleaseModuleEnumLock+0x1c, calling ntdll!RtlReleaseSRWLockShared
    00000030497bf2e0 00007ffbb44ec0f4 ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x4c
    00000030497bf300 00007ffbb450be9b ntdll!LdrpReleaseLoaderLock+0x27, calling ntdll!LdrpReleaseModuleEnumLock
    00000030497bf340 00007ffbb44ebe53 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x1f3, calling ntdll!LdrpReleaseLoaderLock
    00000030497bf3b0 00007ffbb44ebd93 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x133, calling ntdll!RtlActivateActivationContextUnsafeFast
    00000030497bf3b8 00007ffbb44ebdc6 ntdll!LdrpInitializeThread+0x166, calling ntdll!RtlDeactivateActivationContextUnsafeFast
    00000030497bf420 00007ffbb44e8d73 ntdll!_LdrpInitialize+0x93, calling ntdll!NtTestAlert
    00000030497bf490 00007ffbb44e8c98 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0x18, calling ntdll!NtContinue
    00000030497bf900 00007ffba8393e07 clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x66, calling clr!_chkstk
    00000030497bf940 00007ffbb43613d2 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
    00000030497bf970 00007ffbb44e54e4 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

My doubt is in these 3 lines -:

```
ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xd7, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
00000030497bf140 00007ffbb4500d07 ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0xd7, calling ntdll!RtlpLowFragHeapAllocFromContext
00000030497bf180 00007ffbac0c51bd gzip!DllMainCRTStartup+0x139, calling gzip!DllMain
```

Can this thread be cause of high cpu usage ?

Comment: I already have run !runaway command, this is one of the stack traces.. and their are many threads with the same stack trace.. just trying to understand what does this stack trace is trying to tell.. Though I doubt, this thread is culprit for cpu usage ..

Comment: Yes. Does that answer your question? Threads are executed on a CPU, so it's the threads that use CPU time and make high CPU. As opposed to the memory. Memory is not executed on the CPU, so it does not cause high CPU trouble. Maybe you want to rephrase the question to get an answer that fits your needs.

Comment: WinDbg is a great tool but imo not the right tool for this job. It can only give you information about one specific point in time. To get a better holistic view of what your application is doing, you should use something like ETW *(or procmon)* and draw conclusions from there. That said, you seem to be compressing something so I would *expect* high CPU.

Comment: it is webapi call.. web api do gzip compression (based on configuration).. How can I see what Is that compressing and that is actually real problem ..?

Comment: If it's a file being compressed, you could use procmon to find out wich one. The analysis part is bit easier then WPA *(ETW)* because of the overwhelming information ETW provides. You still need to xcopy procmon.exe to the production system though and be able to run it as administrator.

Comment: also use ETW and select File/DiskIO in WPRUI to see file/disk data.

Comment: As per article - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742546.aspx I should not focus on this thread.. because it is waiting and perhaps is in sleep mode -WaitForSingleObjectEx and sleeping does not cause cpu usage..

Comment: True. If you keep digging and searching you'll eventually reach the point where you figure out that WinDbg is not the right tool for this job and you need another one like ETW ;)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I gave it up, he doesn't want to understand this. I let him now waste his time with the wrong tools.

Comment: @magicandre1981 - I could understand if OP is working in an environment where it's unlikely to get permission to change anything or where it's an administration nightmare to do so. Eventually though, they are going to have to bite the bullet.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As per article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742546.aspx  I should not focus on this thread.. because it is waiting and perhaps is in sleep mode -WaitForSingleObjectEx and sleeping does not cause cpu usage..

A few more resources if somebody is in same situation -:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/-NET-Debugging-Stater-Kit-for-the-Production-Environment

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms182372.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Windbg is not the right tool for this job. Dumps are only snapshots so you have no idea what happened before. Use ETW and here the CPU Sampling, which sums all calls and shows you in detail the CPU usage.

Install the Windows Performance Toolkit which is part of the Windows 10 SDK ([V1607 works](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) on Win8/8.1(Server2012/R2) and Win10 or the [V1511 SDK](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=698771) if you use Windows 7/Server2008R2)), run `WPRUi.exe` and select `CPU Usage`

[image]

and press on `Start`. Capture 1 minute of the high CPU usage and next click on `Save`. Open the generated ETL with WPA.exe (Perf analyzer), drag and drop the `CPU Usage (Sampled)` graph to the analysys pane

[image]

and [load the Debug Symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/load-symbols-or-configure-symbol-paths). Now select your process in the graph, zoom in and expand the stack, here you see the weight of the CPU usage of all calls

In this sample most CPU usage from Internet Explorer comes from HTML stuff.

For .NET applications WPA shows you .net related groupings like GC or JIT:

[image]

Comment: Issue is in production environment, support wont allow installing tool.

Comment: Support most likely doesn't know what ETW is. Explain to them that this is what Microsoft uses to troubleshoot systems, [including production systems](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/robertsmith/2012/02/07/analyzing-storage-performance-using-the-windows-performance-analysis-toolkit-wpt/). If you are still not allowed to xcopy the files necessary to start a trace, I would kindly hand over the case to them or ask what their preference is: adding your own heavyweight logging to further analyze the issue or use the lightweight build-in logging that Microsoft provides.

Comment: ETW is the BEST support tool in production, the tool can by xcopied to the server and you use also use the comamndlin version for scripts. . Everyone who says ETW is bad, is an uneducated troll. your support should be fired

Comment: Note also that Microsoft provides tools builtin to Windows that allows these ETW traces to be captured and analyzed on different machines. For example, [logman](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/logman) should be installed by default. Another useful tool for analysis of the captured ETL file is [PerfView](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview).

Answer (score 3):

The first WinDBG command you will want to run is: `!runaway`.
This command will show you which thread was using the CPU for the longest time.
After receiving input from this command we can think forward on what that is going on...

Comment: If !runaway gives a high usage, the thread may currently do something totally unrelated to the high CPU cause. !runaway produces many false positives.

Comment: @Thomas: !runaway shows which thread was using the CPU for the longest period of time, totaly from the begining of the application. If your executable is exausting the CPU then !runaway should show you the most problematic threads in the beginning of the list, which will help you analyze what intensive tasks you are doing. I used it many times and never did encounter false positives.

Comment: Then you were lucky that you captured the state at the time where the correct stack is currently executed. !runaway may report a thread that was active 3 days ago and does nothing at the moment.

Comment: This is where I am confused... the above thread, whose stack trace I have provided is active as per dump for last 13 hours, looking at the trace it seems like it is doing nothing and waiting for clr to provide some work.. but I as per me, it should not be inactive for such a long time or it is actually stuck somewhere that I don't know ..

Comment: and yes like I mentioned above also .. there are many threads around 70 which are in the same state..

Answer (score -1):

Set correct symbols path after any analysis.
Set at File->Symbol File Path menu:
YOUR_SYMBOLS_PATH;OTHERS_PATH;SRV*C:\symcache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

Try this commands to view managed stack to:

```
.cordll -ve -u -l
ld*
!EEStack
```

Comment: What benefit do you see in !EEStack over !DumpStack? How can performance issues be resolved with it?

Comment: for show some relevant information that could lead to source of the problem. For those who usually investigate crashes this is significant.