# CPU usage of diferrent state of wpf application

Tags: wpf, performance, performance-testing, cpu-usage

I have tried to improve the performance of a WPF application. I found when the window is minimized, the CPU usage will reduce to 0 or very little usage, but when the application display in the front end, the CPU usage will increase to 10% or more. Anyone know why?

Comment: use [WPR/WPA to analyze the CPU usage of your application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856838/1466046)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens on all WPF apps. When an app is minimised and the UI is hidden the WPF app is not having to do much unless you have tasks running on a background thread.

WPF can be quite resource intensive and there is a cost to drawing windows and controls. If there is nothing happening in the background of the app and it no longer has to draw any windows/controls then the CPU usage will likely be zero.