# WPF Animation High CPU Usage

Tags: wpf, performance, xaml, animation, cpu-usage

I realised that WPF animations have a huge impact on cpu usage. My app use infinite animations and there are like 30 in the same time. Lag isn't a problem, CPU usage is a problem, is 30-40%. With only 5 animation it's also 10%. Is this normal ? If not , what can i do ? Maybe it's just my processor ? 
Windows 10 32 bit, Intel E5300. Tried the following:
Use bitmapCache, Set DesiredFrameRate property lower, works but it looks really bad lower than 60, Hardware acceleration is on, RenderCapability.Tier is 2.
Animation stopped = 0-1% cpu usage. I think no code is necessary that's happen with any animation, no matter if it's just a color/opacity change, move, rotation etc, i tried many new projects and combinations.

Comment: Ya that pentium on a 32bit OS isn't exactly ideal these days. What you're seeing sounds expected under those specs.

Comment: use [WPR/WPA to analyze the CPU usage of your application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856838/1466046)