# Visual studio 2017 performance bad

Tags: performance, memory, visual-studio-2017, cpu

Is there a way to increase the performance of Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise?
I have a LOT of spare CPU and memory..., but VS is very laggy and slow and it's almost not using any resources (6% CPU and 6% Memory)?

Comment: Take a look at this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-performance-tips-and-tricks)

Comment: 6% cpu is not much, others have higher idle usage. [analyze the CPU usage with WPRUI/WPA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856838/1466046)