# High CPU Usage with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, owin, windbg, authorize-attribute

We've been recently experiencing a regularly occurring set of CPU spikes on our production server, specifically Tuesday evenings (and sometimes Monday nights), at 15-20 minute intervals (and sometimes less), So far we've narrowed it down to the w3wp.exe (ASP.NET) process, but have not been able to determine the exact reason behind the spikes.

We've tried some online monitoring tools, but they haven't led to any promising results.

The closest result I have found is from using WinDbg, and looking at the process dumps when the CPU spikes occur.

When running the "!syncblk" command, to determine what threads have locks, I receive the following result, which doesn't contain a thread ID for me to investigate futher

```
!syncblk Index SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion Owning Thread
Info  SyncBlock Owner   163 00000000119712e8          410         0
0000000000000000     none    00000004bff6b488
System.Threading.TimerQueue
```

I also tried analyzing some of the longer running threads, and the only commonality I see is the following in the stack trace.

```
000000002863ba28 000000007712c2ea [GCFrame: 000000002863ba28] 
000000002863baf8 000000007712c2ea [HelperMethodFrame_1OBJ: 000000002863baf8] System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait(Boolean, Int32, System.Object)
000000002863bc10 000007fe9cdfaadd System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim.Wait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Threading\ManualResetEventSlim.cs @ 670]
000000002863bcd0 000007fe9cdf9ceb System.Threading.Tasks.Task.SpinThenBlockingWait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 3356]
000000002863bd60 000007fe9cdf946a System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InternalWait(Int32, System.Threading.CancellationToken) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Threading\Tasks\Task.cs @ 3295]
000000002863be60 000007fe9cdf91d5 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task) [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs @ 167]
000000002863be90 000007fe9cd776f1 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin]].GetResult() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs @ 373]
000000002863bec0 000007fe9cd774ab Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync[[Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin]](System.Func`1>)
```

It seems like there is some sort of locking issue in the AspNet.Identity classes, when trying to authenticate the user. This is specifically occurring within in an implementation of the "AuthorizeAttribute" class within ASP.NET Web API, where we are using OWIN to authenticate the user.

Also, some of our other threads that seem to be locked have the following output from WinDbg, but I am not sure if it's related or not.

```
00000000048ddc28 000000007712c2ea [GCFrame: 00000000048ddc28] 
00000000048dde20 000000007712c2ea [GCFrame: 00000000048dde20] 
00000000048dde58 000000007712c2ea [HelperMethodFrame: 00000000048dde58] System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(System.Object)
00000000048ddf50 000007fe9c6403d5 System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Threading\Timer.cs @ 658]
00000000048ddfc0 000007fe9a98ccf3 System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Threading\ThreadPool.cs @ 1260]
00000000048de010 000007fe9a98b143 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\System\Threading\ThreadPool.cs @ 830]
00000000048de578 000007fef8e1afb3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 00000000048de578] 
00000000048de708 000007fef8e1afb3 [ContextTransitionFrame: 00000000048de708] 
00000000048de928 000007fef8e1afb3 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 00000000048de928]
```

Any help on this is definitely appreciated.

UPDATE...
After some more investigation, I seem to have found two different patterns:

First - We have some long-running threads that seem to be waiting on returning non-successful API response (most likely via a cancellation token)

Second - When looking into threads that are blocking other threads, a common theme I see is that it's waiting on timers to expire items from a MemoryCache object.

I'm unsure if what I am looking at it is helpful to determining the cause or not.

Comment: What's your IIS setup? Are you using Web Gardens?

Comment: Are you writing any sort of async code? Calling the `.Wait` method specifically? That is known to cause deadlocks in ASP.NET.

Comment: use [ETW (WPR;/WPA) to analyze high CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856838/1466046)

Comment: Something which is waiting is probably not responsible for a high CPU spike. To analyze a performance issue, you need several crash dumps and build a statistics for the call stacks. Although procdump can generate this kind of crash dumps, it's very hard to analyze. Use other tools, if possible

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far.  We are not in a load balanced environment, and it is one server (although we are considering using load balancing)

Comment: Also, based on analysis from IIS request logs, I've been able to determine the following: we have some requests (which should generally take less than 1 second) taking minutes at a time, and when that occurs, they seem to all result in the "sc-win32-status" code of either 121 (which I believe means "The semaphore timeout period has expired."  It's worth noting that other days of the week have nearly similar usage on the site, and there are no CPU spikes like there are on Tuesdays, and there are no automated jobs running differently on that day of the week that could be causing interference

Comment: Another thing I am trying to determine is whether the issue is caused by a single request (which locks the other requests), or is it culmination of load (i.e. lots of smaller simultaneous requests that result in the CPU spike.  Is there a tool or process recommended to help determine that?

Comment: "I also tried analyzing some of the longer running threads"
If you have only one dump - you really don't know what threads were consuming CPU most of all during the problematic period and because of this you can come to an incorrect conclusions. 
!runaway will show how many CPU thread consumes since the process start. I can make a guess that you will see a thread pool at the top. TPL is executed with thread pool and that correlates with what you see in the stack.

Comment: At first place I'd collect performance counters per thread "Thread\% Processor Time", "Thread\ID Thread", "Thread\ID Process" for w3wp process. And counters from ".NET CLR Memory" also. And try to find a load pattern - high CPU from one thread, couple of threads, many different threads, or, maybe from GC (% Time in GC counter).
With this knowledge you can goo deeper into the dumps and check what threads that causing high CPU are doing.

Comment: Also, I would recommend the DebugDiag - free tool from Microsoft (http://debugdiag.com) with which you can easily create dump series manually as well as using rules and conditions. It also contains the reporting feature that can help you to deal with your issue or at least simplify first steps during issue diagnostics.

Comment: So I did originally use DebugDiag, and executed some of the reports, but they didn't yield very meaningful results.  I basically saw there were threads in contention, but it was not obvious what object(s) they were locked/waiting on.  Also, I ran the WinDbg process a few times, and each time the analysis yields that a thread with ID "0" basically has a lock on System.Threading.TimerQueue.  I don't believe we are using that anywhere in our app, so I am not sure what to do with that information.

Comment: the ETW way also captures hang data. Also use [WPA to analyze the hang](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-43-WPT-Wait-Analysis)